# O Priberam "lavou a cara"!

Tags: discussion, recursos, news

O Priberam lavou a cara!

O site tem um aspeto novo, e retrabalharam o interface e a UX:

- Interface mais polida/bonita.
- Definição de preferências;
- Ilustração das definições com pequenas imagens;
- Pesquisa em pt-PT ou pt-BR;
- Mostra resultados com ou sem o acordo ortográfico;
- Mostra usos da palavra noutras definições, ao fundo (sob "Esta palavra no dicionário").

A interação, pelo menos em Firefox, tem alguns bugs — por exemplo, não consigo guardar preferências.
Apesar disso, acho que é uma melhoria significativa.

Answer (score 3):

## Funcionalidades

Eis uma descrição das funcionalidades novas que vejo:

### Definição de preferências

Pressionando o ícone de uma roldana "⚙" no lado direito da caixa de pesquisa, é possível selecionar preferências:

[image: as preferências que o site permite guardar]

### Ilustrações

Algumas das definições já tinham uma pequena imagem ilustrativa.
Neste novo UI/UX, essa imagem ganhou destaque.

Exemplo: a definição de [espigueiro](https://dicionario.priberam.org/espigueiro):

> [image: um exemplo de uma ilustração, na definição de espigueiro]

### Pesquisa em pt-PT ou pt-BR

Este dicionário permite mudar a pesquisa entre [português-europeu](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portugu%c3%aas-europeu) e [português-brasileiro](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portugu%c3%aas-brasileiro):

Pesquisa em pt-PT:

> [image: uma pesquisa em português europeu pelo termo aspe]

Pesquisa em pt-BR:

> [image: uma pesquisa em português brasileiro pelo termo aspec]

### Pesquisa com ou sem acordo ortográfico

Ao pesquisar (apenas em pt-PT), mostra resultados para antes (aAO) e depois (dAO) do Acordo Ortográfico:

> [image: uma pesquisa mostrando resultados com e sem acordo ortográfico]

Answer (score 2):

Algumas dessas possibilidades já existiam antes da mudança na interface — por exemplo as opções pt-br e pt-pt, ou antes e depois do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990.

E, concordo que a interface está mais moderna, mas penso que menos funcional e, estranhamente, até a qualidade dos resultados parece ter sofrido.

Por exemplo, se procuro por "[apelo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/apelo)", a página retorna, sob um enorme espaço em branco desnecessário, primeiro o verbete de "pelo" e, só abaixo, o correto, da palavra procurada, "apelo" (vide captura de tela abaixo). Esse não é único caso e não me lembro da página ter esses problemas antes desta última alteração.

O comportamento não se altera em diferentes navegadores (embora o espaço em branco — presente no Firefox e Chrome — não esteja presente no Brave, o que pode indicar que se trata de um anúncio não carregado).

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: ui :( devia prioritizar resultados exatos!...